# How to create a numerical class in ARFF file for use in WEKA?

Tags: weka, arff

I have tried to change my class in the ARFF file to the following:

```
@ATTRIBUTE class {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7}
```

However when I load my data set and select the class attribute under the Preprocess tab, it still says the type is nominal.

How do I change it to numeric? There doesn't seem to be anything about this online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like you would define any numeric attribute:

```
@ATTRIBUTE class NUMERIC
```

You can't define a range, though.